# filter objects which are not members of other objects

Tags: django, django-queryset

I tried to get an answer to this previously with no luck.

I have a model that looks like (simplified):

```
class Answer(models.model):
    previous = models.ForeignKey('self')
    id = IntegerField()
```

How can I define a filter to find `Answer` objects which are not the `previous` Answer for any other `Answer` object.

For example:

I have a set of answers `[A1, A2, A3, A4]` with:

```
A1.previous = A2
A2.previous = A4
A3.previous = A1
A4.previous = A1
```

I want to find **A3** since this is the only one in the set which does not have `X.previous = A3` where X is in the set

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work:

```
Answer.objects.exclude(previous__in=Answer.objects.all().values_list('previous', flat=True))
```

Nesting the QS might be very expensive though, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in).